# Need to optimize Teradata query

Tags: query-optimization, teradata

I am trying to optimize the following teradata query. Can anyone please on this. It is taking lot of time to retrieve records.

```
   select top 100 I.item_sku_nbr,L.loc_nbr,MIS.MVNDR_PRTY_ID from 
QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item I,
qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.location L,
qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str IST,
qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str MIS 
    where  MIS.str_LOC_ID = L.loc_id and    
mis.str_loc_id = IST.str_loc_id and     
IST.str_loc_id = L.loc_id and   
MIS.ITEM_STAT_CD = IST.ITEM_STAT_CD and     
IST.ITEM_ID = I.ITEM_ID and     
MIS.ITEM_ID = IST.ITEM_ID       and     
I.ITEM_STAT_CD =  100           and 
IST.curr_rmeth_cd = 2           and
MIS.curr_dsvc_typ_cd = 3        and 
MIS.OK_TO_ORD_FLG = 'Y'  and        
MIS.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31' and  
IST.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31' and 
MIS.ACTV_FLG ='Y' and       
IST.ACTV_FLG ='Y'  and  I.ACTV_FLG='Y'
```

Explain plan for **QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION**:

1) First, we lock QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION in view
     qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.Location for access.

2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION
     in view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.Location by way of an all-rows scan
     with no residual conditions into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is
     built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with
     high confidence to be 10,903 rows (1,613,644 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 0.01 seconds.

3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.

-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.01 seconds.

Explain plan for **qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str** :

1) First, we lock QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view
     qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str for access.

2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.item_str
     in view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str by way of an all-rows scan
     with no residual conditions into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is
     built locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be cached in
     memory, but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The result
     spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool 1 is
     estimated with low confidence to be 1,229,047,917 rows (
     325,697,698,005 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 4
     minutes and 51 seconds.

3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.

-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 4 minutes and 51 seconds.

Explain plan for **QA_US_MASTER.ITEM**:

1) First, we lock QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item
     for access.

2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in
     view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item by way of an all-rows scan with no
     residual conditions into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built
     locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with high
     confidence to be 1,413,284 rows (357,560,852 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 0.40 seconds.

3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.

-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.40 seconds.

Explain plan for **QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR:**

1) First, we lock QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
     qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str for access.

2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
     QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
     qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str by way of an all-rows scan with
     no residual conditions into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built
     locally on the AMPs.  The input table will not be cached in memory,
     but it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The result spool
     file will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool 1 is
     estimated with high confidence to be 1,316,279,746 rows (
     327,753,656,754 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 6
     minutes and 4 seconds.

3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.

-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 6 minutes and 4 seconds.

Explain plan for **Whole query**:

```
  1) First, we lock QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in view QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item
  for access, we lock QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION in view
  qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.location for access, we lock
  QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
  qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str for access, and we lock
  QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str for
  access. 

  2) Next, we execute the following steps in parallel. 
   1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION in
      view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.location by way of an all-rows scan
      with no residual conditions into Spool 3 (all_amps)
      (compressed columns allowed), which is duplicated on all AMPs. 
      The size of Spool 3 is estimated with high confidence to be
      1,013,979 rows (20,279,580 bytes).  The estimated time for
      this step is 0.03 seconds. 

    2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in
      view QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item by way of an all-rows scan with
      a condition of ("(QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in view
      QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item.ITEM_STAT_CD = 100) AND
      (QA_US_MASTER.ITEM in view QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item.ACTV_FLG =
      'Y')") into Spool 4 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed)
      fanned out into 14 hash join partitions, which is duplicated
      on all AMPs.  The size of Spool 4 is estimated with low
      confidence to be 30,819,363 rows (678,025,986 bytes).  The
      estimated time for this step is 0.81 seconds. 

     3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of an
    all-rows scan, which is joined to QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view
    qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str by way of an all-rows scan with a
    condition of 
    ("(QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view
    qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str.CURR_RMETH_CD = 2) AND
     ((QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view
    qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31') AND
    (QA_US_MASTER.item_str in view
    qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str.ACTV_FLG = 'Y'))").  Spool 3 and
    QA_US_MASTER.item_str are joined using a dynamic hash join, with a
    join condition of ("QA_US_MASTER.item_str.STR_LOC_ID = LOC_ID"). 
    The input table QA_US_MASTER.item_str will not be cached in memory. 
    The result goes into Spool 5 (all_amps) (compressed columns
    allowed), which is built locally on the AMPs into 14 hash join
    partitions.  The size of Spool 5 is estimated with no confidence
    to be 69,133,946 rows (2,419,688,110 bytes).  The estimated time
    for this step is 1 minute and 8 seconds. 

    4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of an
   all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 5 (Last Use) by way of an
   all-rows scan.  Spool 4 and Spool 5 are joined using a hash join
   of 14 partitions, with a join condition of ("(ITEM_ID = ITEM_ID)
   AND (ACTV_FLG = ACTV_FLG)").  The result goes into Spool 6
   (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is redistributed by
   the hash code of (QA_US_MASTER.item_str.STR_LOC_ID,
   QA_US_MASTER.item_str.ITEM_STAT_CD, QA_US_MASTER.item_str.ITEM_ID,
   QA_US_MASTER.ITEM.ITEM_ID, QA_US_MASTER.LOCATION.LOC_ID) to all
    AMPs into 33 hash join partitions.  The size of Spool 6 is
   estimated with no confidence to be 36,434,893 rows (1,603,135,292
   bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 9.11 seconds. 

    5) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR
   in view qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str by way of an all-rows
   scan with a condition of ("(QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
   qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str.CURR_DSVC_TYP_CD = 3) AND
    ((QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
   qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31')
   AND ((QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
   qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str.ACTV_FLG = 'Y') AND
   (QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR in view
   qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str.OK_TO_ORD_FLG = 'Y')))") into
   Spool 7 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed) fanned out into 33
   hash join partitions, which is redistributed by the hash code of (
   QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR.ITEM_ID,
   QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR.STR_LOC_ID,
   QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR.ITEM_STAT_CD,
   QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR.ITEM_ID,
   QA_US_MASTER.MVNDR_ITEM_STR.STR_LOC_ID) to all AMPs.  The input
    table will not be cached in memory, but it is eligible for
   synchronized scanning.  The size of Spool 7 is estimated with no
   confidence to be 173,967,551 rows (5,914,896,734 bytes).  The
   estimated time for this step is 2 minutes and 23 seconds. 

   6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of an
   all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of an
   all-rows scan.  Spool 6 and Spool 7 are joined using a hash join
   of 33 partitions, with a join condition of ("(STR_LOC_ID =
   STR_LOC_ID) AND ((ITEM_STAT_CD = ITEM_STAT_CD) AND ((ITEM_ID =
   ITEM_ID) AND ((ACTV_FLG = OK_TO_ORD_FLG) AND ((ACTV_FLG = ACTV_FLG)
   AND ((EFF_END_DT = EFF_END_DT) AND ((ACTV_FLG = ACTV_FLG) AND
   ((OK_TO_ORD_FLG = ACTV_FLG) AND ((ITEM_ID = ITEM_ID) AND
   (STR_LOC_ID = LOC_ID )))))))))").  The result goes into Spool 2
   (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is built locally on
   the AMPs.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with no confidence to
   be 12,939,628 rows (336,430,328 bytes).  The estimated time for
   this step is 4.00 seconds. 

   7) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 2 by way of an
  all-rows scan into Spool 10, which is redistributed by hash code
  to all AMPs.  The result rows are put into Spool 1 (group_amps),
  which is built locally on the AMPs.  This step is used to retrieve
  the TOP 100 rows.  Load distribution optimization is used.
  If this step retrieves less than 100 rows, then execute step 8. 
  The size is estimated with no confidence to be 100 rows (3,200
  bytes). 

  8) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by
  way of an all-rows scan into Spool 10 (Last Use), which is
  redistributed by hash code to all AMPs.  The result rows are put
   into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. 
  This step is used to retrieve the TOP 100 rows.  The size is
  estimated with no confidence to be 100 rows (3,200 bytes).

  9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
  in processing the request.

 -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
 statement 1.
```

Comment: paste the explain plan and stats on each base tables

Comment: what is the explain plan for the whole query?

Comment: Added explain plan for Whole query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no ORDER BY in your query, so you just want 100 random rows?

In Teradata the TOP is done **after** the full result set has been created. You should move the TOP into a Derived Table like:

```
select I.item_sku_nbr,L.loc_nbr,MIS.MVNDR_PRTY_ID from 
QA_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item I,
qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.location L,
(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str) IST,
qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.mvndr_item_str MIS 
    where  MIS.str_LOC_ID = L.loc_id and    
mis.str_loc_id = IST.str_loc_id and     
IST.str_loc_id = L.loc_id and   
MIS.ITEM_STAT_CD = IST.ITEM_STAT_CD and     
IST.ITEM_ID = I.ITEM_ID and     
MIS.ITEM_ID = IST.ITEM_ID       and     
I.ITEM_STAT_CD =  100           and 
IST.curr_rmeth_cd = 2           and
MIS.curr_dsvc_typ_cd = 3        and 
MIS.OK_TO_ORD_FLG = 'Y'  and        
MIS.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31' and  
IST.EFF_END_DT = DATE '9999-12-31' and 
MIS.ACTV_FLG ='Y' and       
IST.ACTV_FLG ='Y'  and  I.ACTV_FLG='Y'
```

Comment: Random rows are fine. But it is showing syntax error in the end of this- (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM qa4_US_MASTER_VIEWS.item_str IST), Expected identifier betwenn ) and ,

Comment: Oops, i put the bracket in the wrong place, the alias name is missing. Edited my query

Comment: @dnoeth Wouldn't using `sample 100` be quicker than `top 100`?

Comment: Probably not quicker, but more random